# Nsis packaging build, not working in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, nsis, packaging, builder

[These two button is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7oVu.png)

I want to build nsis script.
but only in vscode, not working.
when I clicked that button, nothing happens.

A few days ago, I successfully built the same nsis script in same setting.
Today, I didnt change anything. It is not working....

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Hard to say without further details, maybe your configuration is wrong?
What extension are you using? This one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=unSignedsro.VisualInstaller ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about coding, not software support (see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). That said, it appears that Microsoft changed the properties used to identify the language ID of an open file. This change is considered in v3.40.0 of the mentioned extension, so please update.

Comment: @ idleberg: This looks like correct answer, please promote your comment to answer so you can get a credit for it!

Answer (score 0):

Your images show the buttons of NSIS idleberg extension. You can downgrade the extension version from 4 to 3.58.0 (Option is on the right part of the Uninstall button)